# Getting XML attributes in Oracle11g

Tags: sql, xml, oracle11g, xmltype, xmltable

I have a xmlType field with the following data:

```
<itemGroups>

  <itemGroup description="FirstGroup" id="0">
    <items>
      <item description="FirstItem" id="0"/>
      <item description="SecondItem" id="1"/>
    </items>
  </itemGroup>

  <itemGroup description="SecondGroup" id="1">
    <items>
        <item description="FirstItem" id="0"/>
        <item description="SecondItem" id="1"/>
    </items>
  </itemGroup>
</itemGroups>
```

And i want to extract the iitemGroup atributes as a list/table/select.
Example:

```
Result:
    DESCRIPTION ID 
    ----------- -----
     FirstGroup 0
    SecondGroup 1
```

I've tried using `XMLELEMENT` , `XMLTABLE` , `EXTRACT`, also with getClobVal() with no success.

As i cannot create new tables or procedures it would be best to solve this using only SELECT for now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your attempt with XMLTable, but it's fairly straightforward, referencing the attributes with `@attribute`:

```
-- CTE for dummy data
with t (xml) as (
  select xmltype('<itemGroups>

  <itemGroup description="FirstGroup" id="0">
    <items>
      <item description="FirstItem" id="0"/>
      <item description="SecondItem" id="1"/>
    </items>
  </itemGroup>

  <itemGroup description="SecondGroup" id="1">
    <items>
        <item description="FirstItem" id="0"/>
        <item description="SecondItem" id="1"/>
    </items>
  </itemGroup>
</itemGroups>') from dual
)
-- end of CTE
select x.*
from t
cross join xmltable (
  '/itemGroups/itemGroup'
  passing t.xml
  columns description varchar2(20) path '@description',
    id number path '@id'
) x;
```

which gets:

```
DESCRIPTION              ID
-------------------- ------
FirstGroup                0
SecondGroup               1
```